# Hiding cell in UITableView (in Xamarin)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I want to hide a cell based on whether or not it has any data for a particular user. My current approach causes an error `the requested operation resulted in a stack overflow`.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        ...
        cell.TextLabel.Text = items.Keys.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
        cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = items[items.Keys.ElementAt(indexPath.Row)];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.DetailTextLabel.Text)){
            cell.Hidden = true;
            cell.Tag = 3;
        }
        return cell;
    }

public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath); //ERROR HERE
        if (cell.Tag == 3)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return base.GetHeightForRow(tableView, indexPath);
    }
```

How can I avoid this error and properly hide a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `GetCell()` calls `GetHeightForRow()` which calls `GetCell()` which calls `GetHeightForRow()`...that's where your stack overflow is coming from.

You should not use the visual representation (= the cell) to determine whether a row should be visible or not. Your (data) model should be responsible for this. In other words: whatever object type your `items` dictionary contains (maybe it's of type `Person` - I don't know), it should have a property `IsVisible` or something similar. Then in `GetHeightForRow()` you access the item and inspect the property and decide what the row height will be and return 0 for an invisible row.

By the way: I'm not aware of the context of your code above (*), but in general you should *not* call `base.GetHeightForRow()`. The method natively is part of a delegate which is implemented as an ObjectiveC protocol. This means, there is no `base`.

(*) If you derive from `UITableViewSource` or `UITableViewDataSource` there's no side effects when calling `base` but if you implement the methods directly in a `UITableViewController` you might see a `You_Should_Not_Call_Base_Exception`.

Comment: Thanks! I had brain fart moment there (been away from this ios project for a week) and forgot about the manipulation of data structures typically involved with tables.